# Electric forces in dynamic conditions

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law, coulombs-law

The coulomb's law is limited to static charges. This made me think:

1. Is it  because the distance is not exactly defined when charges are moving so the dynamic condition isn't very much pertinent to Coulomb's law because of it? Or is it because the force of interaction itself changes (that is, it is different from the force in the static condition) due to magnetic fields and other reasons and since the coulomb's law doesn't mention these reasons, we can't calculate the force?
2. If the either of the above assertion is true, is there a method to find the force in dynamic conditions or the interaction between charges become insignificant when they are moving?
3. Apart from that, Gauss law is applicable in all frames of reference, does that mean we can find electric field intensity in all frames?

Comment: Electrodynamics deals moving charges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In electrodynamics, the Coulomb's law is not applicable since the charges are moving and you need to take into account that the information that the charges are moving can not travel faster than light. The Coulomb's law is only static.
2. You need to use [retarded potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_potential) in order to deal with these moving charges. Once you get the retarded potential, you can compute the field and then the force on any particle.
3. Yes but you need to take into account [special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity). That means if you compute the electric field in a given frame of reference, you need to use relativity's formulas in order to translate it into another frame.